# How do you wish someone a successful Ramadan

Tags: ramadan

I have a hard-working colleague that I meet for a breakfast networking event each week. He seemed, understandably, drained at yesterday's event. I'd like to express some kind of encouragement and empathy, but the phrases that come to mind all seem to either; miss the point (e.g. 'good luck'); be inappropriate (e.g. 'go get 'em'); or be awkwardly lengthy, overly personal, and based on poorly-grounded presumptions about of the point of fasting (e.g. 'I hope your fast today helps you to progress in your relationship with God').

What's an appropriate way to encourage a person and wish him/her success during Ramadan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply say "Happy Ramadan" or "Keep it up, its a good work" depending on whichever you feel right at the moment